# Select an element and all its descendant elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, descendant

To select an element *and* all its descendant elements:

```
.media, .media * {color: #f00;}
```

Is there just one selector I can use instead of two selectors separated by a comma? I'm looking for a more efficient way to type this.

Comment: Is there a better solution today, in 2020?

Comment: Basically, CSS is not intended to work this way. Applying same properties on every descendants is a bad practice. `.media {color: #f00}` is enough, as every descendant will "inherit" this property instead of "setting" it, unless an other rule apply (like color of a link, for instance). This is a part of what is called "cascading" stylesheet.

Comment: @Charles-ÉdouardCoste Yes, that would work for the properties that are inherited. However, not all CSS properties are inherited, such as `display` for example.

Comment: Sure. But it would be weird to indiscriminately apply such property on *every* descendant instead of grouping by classes… By experience, when something seems missing in CSS, I realize later that I was not supposed to do what I wanted to do with it. :D

Comment: In 2023, recent developments in the CSS standard offer interesting alternatives. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) you have the `descendant-or-self` [axis](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

But there is no such selector in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

In 2023, recent additions to CSS syntax and available pseudo-classes bring some interesting alternative ways to tackle this (although still not as ideal as a truly native *self-or-descendant* combinator).

Let's consider a hypothetical `.prose` class that identifies a site's authored content, which can be delivered either in e.g. `<article>` or `<section>` blocks with nested structure, or in e.g. `<p>` or `<blockquote>` elements that directly contain text.

With only strict descendant combinators and traditional CSS syntax, elements such as `<p>` and `<blockquote>` require the addition of a (probably un-semantic) wrapper, such as a `<div>` element.

Alternatively, each CSS rule can be written in a way that matches both self and descendants, but this involves repetitive (and error-prone) boilerplate:

```css
h1.prose, .prose h1 {...}
h2.prose, .prose h2 {...}
h3.prose, .prose h3 {...}
h4.prose, .prose h4 {...}
h5.prose, .prose h5 {...}
h6.prose, .prose h6 {...}

p.prose, .prose p {...}

blockquote.prose, .prose blockquote {...}

/* And so forth... */
```

Leveraging recent CSS developments, the above can be re-written in the following way:

```css
.prose, .prose * {
    
    &:is(h1) {...}
    &:is(h2) {...}
    &:is(h3) {...}
    &:is(h4) {...}
    &:is(h5) {...}
    &:is(h6) {...}
    
    &:is(p) {...}

    &:is(blockquote) {...}

    /* Alternatively, the :where() pseudo-class can also be used,
       which differs in how specificity is calculated. */
}
```

Obviously, the `&:is(...)` part is still boilerplate, but repetition has been cut down significantly, which can be considered an improvement.

**Caveat:** As of May 2023, browser support for native CSS nesting is still a work-in-progress (see https://caniuse.com/css-nesting) and CSS code that takes advantage of it should be converted to non-nested syntax (using, for example, the *postcss-nesting* plugin). The `:is()` pseudo-class enjoys more widespread support (see https://caniuse.com/?search=is).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another interesting way to tackle this problem that leverages CSS variables (a.k.a. *custom properties*), suitable for toggling individual properties on the presence of what might be called "contextual classes", whether such classes are defined **on the element itself or on one of its ancestors**.

```css
:root {
    --ctx-media: ;
    --ctx-not-media: initial;
}

.media {
    --ctx-media: initial;
    --ctx-not-media: ;
}

* {
    color: var(--ctx-media, #f00) 
           var(--ctx-not-media, inherit);
}
```

The `--ctx-media` variable is defined to a single space on the root element and `--ctx-not-media` is undefined (the `--ctx-not-media: initial` property in the `:root` rule is not really needed since all variables are undefined by default, but I nonetheless provided it for visual symmetry). Note that CSS variables are inherited by default, unless defined otherwise in a *@property* at-rule. Wherever the *media* class is applied, `--ctx-media` becomes undefined and `--ctx-not-media` becomes defined to a single space for the element itself **and all of its descendants**.

Moving on to the *color* property, whichever CSS variable is defined expands to a single space, and whichever is undefined expands to its fallback value. Since whitespaces around property values are semantically inert, the resulting value remains valid. The *inherit* value may be replaced by whatever value is desired for non-media content. Note that both cases **must** be included in the definition of the property value. Leaving out one case will resolve to invalid CSS:

```css
* {
    /* WRONG!!! Will resolve to `color: ;` when --ctx-media is defined */
    color: var(--ctx-media, #f00);
}
```

Now, the *inherit* value — or whatever other "non-media" value — might cause issues in situations where the property isn't inherited (e.g. *margin* or *padding*), or when it can have multiple other values depending on context, and you just want it to remain unchanged. In such situations, one solution that does not involve creating `--ctx-*` variables for every possible case is to leverage yet another recent addition to CSS, namely layers:

```css
:root {
    --ctx-media: ;
    --ctx-not-media: initial;
}

.media {
    --ctx-media: initial;
    --ctx-not-media: ;
}

@layer media {
    * {
        color: var(--ctx-media, #f00) 
               var(--ctx-not-media, revert-layer);
    }
}
```

Note that leaving out layering altogether and using a default value of *revert* instead of *revert-layer* will not work because the value would then be reverted to what it was before the application of the whole stylesheet, not to its next less specific overridden definition within the same stylesheet.

This pattern can handle any number of mutually exclusive cases, even handling nesting of contexts and ensuring exclusivity over their corresponding styling (since variables defined for the last contextual class declared on an element will override previously defined variables), e.g.:

```css
:root,
.default {
    --ctx-default: initial;
    --ctx-prose:   ;
    --ctx-media:   ;
}

.prose {
    --ctx-default: ;
    --ctx-prose:   initial;
    --ctx-media:   ;
}

.media {
    --ctx-default: ;
    --ctx-prose:   ;
    --ctx-media:   initial;
}

@layer media {
    * {
        color: var(--ctx-default, revert-layer) 
               var(--ctx-prose, #f00)
               var(--ctx-media, #00f);
    }
}

/*
The following element has `prose` styling: <div class="media prose">...</div>
The following element has `media` styling: <div class="default media">...</div>
*/
```

This is, of course, more verbose than a simple `.media, .media * {...}` selector when only one rule is involved. However, assuming that `*` is a placeholder for a hypothetical collection of rules that style elements in a "media" context, this is where the whole benefit of this approach is realized.

Both CSS layers and custom properties enjoy widespread support among browsers.